# Why is my SVR model giving a r2_score of 0 while Linear regression and xgboost gives .7 and .8 on same data

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, svm, feature-engineering

I have preprocessed my data and fitting various models on my data to see the performance of each of these models. My code:

```
# standardize the data using Robust Scaler

rc = RobustScaler()
X_train = rc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = rc.transform(X_test)
```

using linear regression model

```
regr = LinearRegression() 
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)

train_score = regr.score(X_train, y_train)
#print training score
print("training score: ", np.round(train_score,2))

# making predictions on test data
y_pred_test=regr.predict(X_test)  
test_score = regr.score(X_test, y_test)
print("test score:", np.round(test_score,2))
```

gives output

```
training score:  0.73
test score: 0.74
```

XGBoost

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

model = XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

train_score = model.score(X_train, y_train)
print("training score: ", np.round(train_score,2))

# making predictions on test data
y_pred_test=model.predict(X_test)  
test_score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print("test score:", np.round(test_score,2))
```

gives output

```
training score:  0.89
test score: 0.82
```

when I try with SVR model

```
# fitting SVR model

svr = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
svr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred_train = svr.predict(X_train)
train_score = svr.score(X_train, y_train)

#print training score
print("training score: ", np.round(train_score,2))

# making predictions on test data
y_pred_test=svr.predict(X_test)  
test_score = svr.score(X_test, y_test)
print("test score:", np.round(test_score,2))
```

My output

```
training score:  -0.0
test score: -0.0
```

I do not understand why my svr model is giving a score of 0. Even if it performs bad to an extent, I expect score values to decrease but not 0. Where might I be going wrong?

Comment: adding parameters to my svr model as `svr = SVR(C= 20, epsilon= 0.008, gamma=0.0003)` has given decent results with score ~ 0.7

Comment: That is why such questions are actually not a good fit for SO; we don't have your data, we cannot experiment, and the fact that you tried with the default settings and did not get good results does not say anything on its own. We cannot offer anything but speculations.

Comment: I could have understood if the results were not good with default settings, but getting scores as 0, might indicate some error and wanted to get the help of SO here.

Comment: for example https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46444/model-score-and-r2-score-giving-different-values-for-a-regression-model . Though we don't have data in it, I feel the answer was very helpful.

Comment: I get it, but your code is actually very simple and straightforward.